# Does searchd have to be restarted every time sphinx.conf is modified?

Tags: sphinx

I'm trying to wrap my head around Sphinx, but I'm a newbie and it's a lot to take in..

One thing I'm a little confused about is whether the searchd process has to be restarted every time sphinx.conf is modified. So, in other words, do I need to connect to my server via SSH and run this

```
killall searchd
/usr/local/bin/searchd --config path/to/sphinx.conf
```

every time I make a change to my sphinx.conf file?

Also, do I need to immediately run the indexer

```
/usr/local/bin/indexer --config path/to/sphinx.conf --all --rotate
```

immediately after restarting searchd, or can I wait until my cron job (the above command, run every half hour) runs?

Side note: There is [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503721/when-updating-an-index-in-sphinx-conf-is-restarting-searchd-in-sphinx-always-req), but it's two years old and the two answers are polar opposites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to that question still stands :)

Generally you only need to restart it if you change the 'searchd' settings. To load new indexes just use indexer to build the index, and with --rotate will cause searchd to reload.

btw, even if you do want to stop searchd, DON'T use killall!! Use `searchd --stop` instead.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help! What's wrong with `killall`? I used that because someone suggested it on the Sphinx forum.

Comment: Killall is like sending in a mob of security guards to clear a room. It works but is kind heavy handed, thinks likly to get broken and trampled. Better first just to ask the leader to peacefully leave - then they can packup and leave nothing broken. (and using killall -9 would be equivalent to using a water hose - it will leave a mess)  - probably what you read was old - before --stop introduced (becasuse it better way anyway)